# How to use docker command in container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker command in container on the centos 7.8
I already installed docker at the centos and want to use docker command in the docker container.

So, I added volume in the docker compose file like below.

```
services:
  test_container:
    container_name: test
    image: app:${DOCKER_TAG}    
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 80:3000    
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT: develop      
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker   
      - /lib/systemd/system/docker.service:/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /etc/sysconfig/docker:/etc/sysconfig/docker
```

But when I run docker compose and use docker command in the container, it shows like this.

```
You don't have either docker-client or docker-client-latest installed. Please install either one and retry.
```

How could I fix this? or How could I use the docker command in docker container?

Thank you for reading my questions.

Comment: Can you show your image's Dockerfile?  You would need to install a `docker` binary using the distribution's package manager; don't try to bind-mount one from the host (which could be a different OS or have incompatible shared-library dependencies).

Comment: (Obligatory reminder: anyone who can access the Docker socket can pretty trivially root the entire host.  Consider carefully whether you _need_ to directly manipulate containers; for many use cases there are much safer alternatives.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to run docker in a docker container, you should use "DinD"( docker in docker ) with privileges. Something like this should work;

```
docker run --privileged -d docker:find
```

Another option - instead of starting “child” containers like DinD, it will start “sibling” containers.

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
       -ti docker
```

For docker compose;

```
version: "2"

services:

  docker-in-docker:
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    expose:
      - 2375
      - 2376

  node1:
    image: docker
    links:
      - docker-in-docker
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
    command: docker ps -a
```

Comment: I'm running docker by using docker compose.
My docker compose file is like this.
```image: app:${DOCKER_TAG}    
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 80:3000    
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT: develop      
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker   
      - /lib/systemd/system/docker.service:/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /etc/sysconfig/docker:/etc/sysconfig/docker```
Where should I add option docker:dind?